# How can I install xfce4-screenshooter newer than 1.9.7 in Xubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, xubuntu, clipboard, screenshot

There is no screenshot on the clipboard when calling my screenshot-shortcut `xfce4-screenshooter -rc` or `xfce4-screenshooter -mcw`. I first asked a question on https://gitlab.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-screenshooter/-/issues/60 but finally I was directed here because it was not the right forum.

I am using xfce4-screenshooter 1.9.7 under Xubuntu 18.04.5 LTS currently with kernel 5.4.0-80-generic x86_64.

I have created various keyboard shortcuts, namely:

- `xfce4-screenshooter -rc` to capture a rectangular region of my screen to the clipboard,
- `xfce4-screenshooter -mcw` to capture the actual window with mouse pointer to the clipboard,
- `xfce4-screenshooter -fmd 7 -o gimp-2.8` for a delayed screenshot to be sent to gimp in order to select the region of interest there.

Sometimes the first and the second one of them don't work. The first one shows me the cursor cross and lets me select a region (which proves that xfce4-screenshooter is involved), but after selecting the region no screenshot can be pasted from the clipboard. The target application (in many cases LO Writer or Gimp) waits for a long time before it tells me that there is nothing on the clipboard, or in the case of LO Writer, it just pastes some text which happened to be on the clipboard before my screenshot. In case of Gimp, it tells me, that no image data are on the clipboard.

I have not installed any special clipboard manager like ClipIt or the like. In fact I was unaware about the existence of such programs. But since I was asked in the other forum whether I use a clipboard manager: I did not install any of them actively and I don't even know the name of the program which actually manages the clipboard. It is definitely neither ClipIt nor xclipboard. If it is part of X: The version of my X is "X.Org X Server 1.20.8".

In the other forum I was recommended to try with xfce4-screenshooter version 1.9.9 or 1.9.8.

Unfortunately I was unable to find the right package to install a more recent version of xfce4-screenshoter on my Xubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. Instead I ruined my system running into dependence problems. Fortunately I could easily reinstall a recent image to overcome this bigger problem.

**From where can I find a package for xfce4-screenshooter version 1.9.9 or 1.9.8. to be installed on my system?**

Comment: FYI: Are you aware that *flavors* of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that has passed it's EOL.  (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ or a UWN - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses highlights the EOL notices for Lubuntu/Ubuntu-MATE/Kubuntu/Ubuntu-Budgie; Xubuntu didn't announce EOL but refer https://xubuntu.org/release/18-04/ you'll see it's 29 April 2021)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Answer (score 0):

You can manually download and install xfce4-screenshooter 1.98 from the default Ubuntu 21.10 repositories in Ubuntu 21.04. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xfce4-screenshooter/xfce4-screenshooter_1.9.8-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./xfce4-screenshooter/xfce4-screenshooter_1.9.8-1_amd64.deb
```